# Proving NP Completeness of "the project manager's problem"

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, np-complete

Suppose we have a list of basic/'atomic' tasks $\{p_1, ..., p_n\}$ and each task has an associated cost $c_i$ for all $i \leq n$.

Morover, we have a list of projects $P_1,..., P_m$ which are collections of tasks, i.e, $P_k \subseteq \{p_1,...,p_n\}$ for each $k\leq m$. Completing each project $P_j$ gives us a reward $R_j$.

Given an input cost of $C$ and reward of $R$, the problem is: Is there a set of which atomic tasks to do so that the total cost is $\leq C$ and the total reward is $\geq R$?

Given the problem above- I want to see that it is NP-complete.

(Remark: I don't think it really matters but tasks can "double count" for multiple projects: meaning if $p_i \in P_j,P_k$ then doing one instance of $p_i$ contributes towards the completion of both $P_j$ and $P_k$ rather than having to do the same task twice for both projects).

Clearly this is NP. Checking a solution works is in fact linear.

I'm not sure how to show NP-completeness.

My first instinct was to show Knapsack could be reduced to this of course. In knapsack, if I'm given a number of items with values $v_i$ and weights $w_i$, I want to choose values to 'pack' so as to not exceed total weight of $W$ while retaining at least value $V$.

Given a knapsack problem I was thinking about converting it to our problem by making each 'item' a project with reward $= v_i$. Then I was simply thinking of making each project consisting of only one atomic task of cost $w_i$. This eliminates overlap between projects of course (so that in the knapsack problem you don't accidentally pack 'half' of one item, etc). I think this is a valid problem, but it seems too simple with the projects and the atomic tasks being the same thing and each project is completely distinct from the other with no overlap.

Is this a valid reduction? Or should I be looking at something else (ex: partitions or subset sums)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your reduction works. Note that it is ok to have knapsack problems converted into simple one-task projects with no overlap; that just shows that knapsack problems are, in a way, the simplest kind of project management problem.

Given that the purpose of the reduction is to show that solving knapsacks is easy when you can easily solve project management, the fact that the reduction makes knapsacks into simple project management instances isn't a problem.

### If you can solve project management efficiently, you can solve knapsack, too.

Suppose you have an algorithm $f$ that efficiently solves any project management problem in polynomial time.

Given a knapsack problem consisting of objects of a certain weight $w_i$ and value $v_i$ and a weight limit $W$ on the bag, you're trying to find a combination of objects which maximizes total value while remaining under the weight limit.

Form the corresponding project management problem. Convert each object into a single-task project $P_i=\{p_i\}$ whose task-cost is equal to the weight $w_i$ and whose reward is equal to the value $v_i$. Set the overall cost limit to the weight limit $W$.

Apply $f$ to this problem, with the reward level set initially set to $R=0$. If $f$ says that the problem is solvable, increase $R$ to 1 and re-run the experiment. Keep incrementally increasing $R$ and re-running the experiment until (1) $f$ says that it's impossible to achieve reward $R$, or (2) the reward $R$ maxes out at $R=\sum_i v_i$.  This loop runs in polynomial time.

Now you know the maximum value $R$ achievable for your knapsack problem— you've solved an arbitrary knapsack problem in polynomial time using a polynomial-time subroutine for project management.

Because knapsack problems are NP-complete, the project management problem is NP-complete.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to write the corresponding optimization problem as an integer linear programming problem.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether task $p_i$ is performed, and let binary decision variable $y_j$ indicate whether project $P_j$ is completed.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{j=1}^m R_j y_j$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n C_i x_i &\le C \tag1 \\
y_j &\le x_i && \text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $i\in P_j$} \tag2
\end{align}
If you have a way to solve this problem, then you can indeed solve an arbitrary $0$-$1$ knapsack problem by taking $m=n$ and $P_j=\{j\}$ for all $j$ because then $y_j=x_j$ is optimal and you can eliminate $(2)$ and maximize $\sum_{i=1}^n R_i x_i$ subject to $(1)$.

Comment: Right, so this is basically what I said- where you make each project into its own separate task. Thanks!


I was wondering, if we now had the extra condition that $c_j = R_j = 1$ always (i.e, the costs of tasks and rewards of projects are always $1$) can you still reduce an arbitrary 0-1 knapsack? I was thinking you could do this by creating weight-many duplicates of each task (corresponding to an item) and reward-many duplicates of a project which each consists of these weight many tasks. This will force you to satisfy reward many projects at the same time. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Does your arbitrary knapsack problem have integer-valued weights and rewards?

Comment: Good point. Is integer valued knapsack still NP-complete?